# How can I update Angular version 11 to latest version with all package and tools

Tags: angular

after updating when I ran the project  with ng serve
i get a error.

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'

Answer (score 4):

If you are updating to latest version then you have to update to each major versions first.
It is like:

```
11 ---> 12 ---> 13 ---> 14
```

There could be possibilities like it might have skipped some modules to update. So angular suggests to update to next major version first.

[Check the steps here](https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-14.0)

Answer (score -1):

Try delete current module (@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling) and try install again :

- npm i @angular/compiler-cli --save dev